# Comparing Dedekind zeta functions

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, zeta-functions

It is known that non-isomorphic number fields can share the same
Dedekind zeta function.  However, there don't appear to be any 
examples of very low degree so in these cases the zeta function must
determine the field.  How hard is it to show this?

Questions: (1) If K is a cubic extension of the rationals, how can
one recover$\,$  K$\,$ from $\,$$\zeta_K$(s) ?

$\quad$$\quad$$\quad$$\quad$$\,$(2) Are there any near misses where one zeta function is almost but not quite equal to another?  That is, if two Dedekind zeta functions (expanded as Dirichlet series) agree for all but finitely many
terms, must they be identical?

Thanks.

Comment: related to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/80403/number-fields-with-same-zeta-function